# Spring Retry - Exception problem and retries

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception, spring-retry

How can we catch two different exceptions (ex. from `.lang` and `.io` packages) in the same block of `@Retryable` method. One, we return an `IOException` and the other we retry the method.

```
@Retryable(value = {Exception.calss } ,maxAttempts = 3, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 3000))
public String getInfo() {
    try {
        //here we have an executive code that may have an IOException
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        //And here i would catch the Exception 
        throw new Exception();
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [`include`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-retry/docs/api/current/org/springframework/retry/annotation/Retryable.html#include--) parameter of the annotation to handle multiple various exceptions:

```
@Retryable(
    include = { IllegalAccessException.class, IOException.class }, 
    maxAttempts = 3, 
    backoff = @Backoff(delay = 3000))
public String getInfo() {
    // some code
}
```